# Actionscript 3 using keyboard to focus on HTML elements inside a TextArea

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, accessibility

I am attempting to add section 508 (Accessibility) compliance to an application built on Actionscript 3. We have popups triggered by HTML links in text. One of the requirements of the section 508 standard is that the entire application be navigable with the keyboard, including any uses of the anchor tag  in the text.

How do I assign focus to an anchor that is present inside a TextField or TextArea object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I know you cannot do this.

the closest thing to targeting elements within an HTML TextField would be using the [getImageReference()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#getImageReference()) method..

Answer (score 1):

It is true that natively, especially with the standard TextField you can't have "accessible" anchor links, that's why you need to "fake" it.
This is how I do it (in a form of component TextPanel :-) to encapsulate all necessery functionality):

1. any time new text is applied (setLabel) I'm checking for indication of a link ("a href's")
2. for each a href that was found I'm generating the faked button that hasn't got focusrect and has accessibility set up
3. tab index for that component is the textfield and following faked buttons (link buttons)

the button works only when user tabs (this is for screen reader and for keyboard users), also you can't make them to be read inline with text so the links are read after text. I mean with TextField you can't.

When user will click on link using mouse the flash.events.TextEvent event is triggered
when user will click the link faked button it will be done using either space or enter so you have to catch CLICK event and dispatch flash.events.TextEvent.

Best regards